# Code specifically for Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, cloud

I heard that apps don’t port directly and they have to be specifically written to work with Azure.  I’m new to Azure and did some reading but I don’t see anything from their site or documentation that suggests that you must specifically code for Azure, so is it true?

If this question is better suited for another StackExchange site please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should take a look at the Windows Azure [Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=413E88F8-5966-4A83-B309-53B7B77EDF78&displaylang=en) to see some introductory project labs.

While you theoretically can just "drop in" some apps into a Windows Azure VM, it hardly makes sense to do so. Some apps can be migrated with only minor changes, such as an asp.net website - session state is easily handled by AppFabric Cache, and the Web Role VM is Windows Server 2008 with Full IIS. However, you'd still need to integrate with Windows Azure Diagnostics, to be able to have external visibility to the health of your app.

Further, with the example above, there are more optimal things you can do, such as moving static content to blob storage, and taking load off your VMs. This requires you to upload this content, and then change your IMG and other tag URLs to point to a slightly-different URL.

Just remember that you're moving to Windows Azure to take advantage of its platform and related services, not just to be a rack to host a server. To take advantages of these services, you're going to have to target them specifically, such as:

- Access control services
- Caching
- Connectivity (vpn, service bus)
- Diagnostics
- Database (SQL Azure)
- Synchronization services
- Traffic management across data centers

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat true. Your apps will typically run as-is. You just need to add an azure project to the solution, and add your MVC apps as roles to the Azure Project.

Answer (score 0):

I found O'Reilly's "Programming Windows Azure" to be a good conceptual introduction to Azure.